# How to disable updates notification on iPhone XR (iOS 12.4), such as for an update of Numbers?

Tags: iphone, numbers

I'm using iOS 12.4 on an iPhone XR. Toggling to "off" at Settings | iTunes & App Stores | Automatic Downloads | Updates does not prevent me from getting notifications that updates are available for the Numbers program that I never use and do not even want on my device. How can I ensure that annoying red badges with this kind of notification never appear?

Comment: Notification on lock screens etc? or the red dot on App Store icon? Former can be done in notification settings-> App Store. Latter hopefully by turning off background app refresh such as in Low power mode.

Comment: If you don't want it & never use it, why not just discard it?

Comment: @Tetsujin or offload it. hardly makes a difference to me though.

Comment: How can I discard Numbers? Slow hovering over an icon on the front page to make all the app icons wobble brings up "x" as a way to delete deletable apps but not Numbers.

Comment: @ruffle that is odd. I don't have any of keynote, pages or numbers. Go to general, storage and find the app. you should be able to offload or delete it.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii - Many thanks! That worked! (Off-topic: any idea how I can delete Health and Wallet? That method doesn't bring up either a discard or a delete option for those.)